# Why do I get "pop index out of range" error when running this?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am writing code to make a bot for the math game "Dandelions" and in order to do so, I take all columns, rows, and diagonals that contain the number 1. Then, with this list of lists that contain the number 1, I need to separate them using a for loop. However, when running this for loop I get an error saying that the pop index is out of range, but when I run the code with each individual i value, I don't get an error. It is the last for loop at the very end of the code that is causing this problem. Please help! Note: Even when running the for loop with a range of 3, it still outputs an error. Only indexes 0 and 2 are outputted.

```
row_1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
row_2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
row_3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
row_4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
row_5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

col_1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
col_2 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
col_3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
col_4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
col_5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

#diagonals 1-9 go from left to right, while diagonals 10-18 go from right to left

dia_1 = [0]
dia_2 = [0, 0]
dia_3 = [0, 0, 0]
dia_4 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
dia_5 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
dia_6 = [0, 0, 0, 0,]
dia_7 = [0, 0, 0]
dia_8 = [0, 0]
dia_9 = [0]

dia_10 = [0]
dia_11 = [0, 0]
dia_12 = [0, 0, 0]
dia_13 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
dia_14 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
dia_15 = [0, 0, 0, 0,]
dia_16 = [0, 0, 0]
dia_17 = [0, 0]
dia_18 = [0]

dia = [dia_1, dia_2, dia_3, dia_4, dia_5, dia_6,
       dia_7, dia_8, dia_9, dia_10, dia_11, dia_12,
       dia_13, dia_14, dia_15, dia_16, dia_17, dia_18]
row = [row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4, row_5]
col = [col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5]
possible = []

for i in dia:
    if 1 in i:
        possible.append(i)

for i in row:
    if 1 in i:
        possible.append(i)

for i in col:
    if 1 in i:
        possible.append(i)

for i in range(0, 4):
    print(possible.pop(i))
```

Comment: Here's a hint: ``i`` keeps increasing (0 to 3) while your list ``possible`` is shrinking as you're removing items with ``pop``.

Answer (score 0):

The for loops that are giving you the out-of-range error wrap them on a try-except block, in the exception add new logic to ignore or fix the out of range; for instance:

```
try:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(possible.pop(i))
except:
    #correct your out-of-range:
    pass
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem really. The output is still only diagonal 4 and row 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you did not get my hint and the only answer so far is not very helpful.

To reproduce the problem, let's hard-code `possible`, since everything before the last loop does not really matter.

```
possible = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
print(f"Possible before loop: {possible}")
for i in range(0, 4):
    print(f"Item at pos {i}: {possible.pop(i)}")
    print(f"Possible after pop: {possible}")
```

Output:

```
Possible before loop: [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
Item at pos 0: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
Possible after pop: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
Item at pos 1: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Possible after pop: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>     
    print(f"Item at pos {i}: {possible.pop(i)}")
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Explanation:

As I said before, `i` keeps increasing, but at the same time, you are removing items from `possible`.

After the first iteration `possible` is `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]`.

But during the next (the second) iteration, you are popping the item at index `1`, which is `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` - you were probably expecting `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.

During the third iteration, possible only holds two items: `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]` but you are trying to pop the item at index `2`, which is when the `pop index out of range` error happens.

Why not simple iterate your list and print the items instead of popping them?

```
possible = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
for item in possible:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```